# form post with file attach throws network error / React Native + react native Image picker

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-image-picker

I am using `react-native-image-picker` to fetch image details and try to upload in https backend server. the request is not successful and it throws network error. It did not esablish the connection with the backend server. The problem is with `formdata` that I am sending. Can you please suggest `header` and other information, if I missed out.

```
  export const postImage = async state => {  

    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('image', {
      uri : state.photo.uri,
      type: state.photo.type,
      name : state.photo.fileName
    });


    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Accept: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
    };

    try {
    return $http.post('/image/save', formData, config)
    .then(response => response)
    .catch(error => error)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

**Environment:**
 - Axios Version ^0.19.2
 - Additional Library Versions [React 16.11.0, React Native 0.62.1]

Answer (score 3):

There's an issue with flipper, upgrading it to 0.39.0 and above works

This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551

Fix: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/993#issuecomment-619823916

```
This should be fixed in version 0.39.0. To upgrade, edit android > gradle.properties

# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.39.0  // edit this manually
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue that I was facing which is close to what you are mentioning is that I was getting  NetworkError when using expo-image-picker and trying to upload the file using `axios`. It was working perfectly in iOS but not working in android.

There are two independent issues at action here. Let's say we get `imageUri` from image-picker, then we would use these following lines of code to upload from the frontend.

```jsx
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('image', {
 uri : imageUri,
 type: "image",
 name: imageUri.split("/").pop()
});
```

The first issue is with the `imageUri` itself. If let's say photo path is `/user/.../path/to/file.jpg`. Then file picker in android would give `imageUri` value as `file:/user/.../path/to/file.jpg` whereas file picker in iOS would give `imageUri` value as `file:///user/.../path/to/file.jpg`.

**The solution for the first issue is to use `file://` instead of `file:` in the `formData` in android.**

The second issue is that we are not using proper mime-type. It is working fine on iOS but not on Android. What makes this worse is that the file-picker package gives the type of the file as "image" and it does not give proper mime-type.

The solution is to use proper mime-type in the `formData` in the field `type`. Ex: mime-type for `.jpg` file would be `image/jpeg` and for `.png` file would be `image/png`. We do not have to do this manually. Instead, **you can use a very famous npm package called [mime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime).**

**The final working solution is:**

```jsx
import mime from "mime";

const newImageUri =  "file:///" + imageUri.split("file:/").join("");

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', {
 uri : newImageUri,
 type: mime.getType(newImageUri),
 name: newImageUri.split("/").pop()
});
```

[Original Answer - forums expo](https://forums.expo.dev/t/network-request-failed-while-uploading-image-to-server/30737/5)

Comment: Thanks so much! The mime-type did it! I was able to get this working without changing the Android uri to `file: //`. Maybe that's because my formData was for a `file` and not an `image`? Nonetheless, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with flipper.Upgrade the flipper version in gradle.properties to 0.43.0+ and it will be fixed

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the mime type matches the file you are uploading.
For me, it was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

change this line: form_data.append('image', data);

To form_data.append('image', JSON.stringify(data));

where data is from the image picker.

from https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/798

You need to add this uesCleartextTraffic="true" to the AndroidManifest.xml file found inside the dir android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

<application ... android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> Then, Because of issue with Flipper Network.

I commented initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())

in this file /android/app/src/main/java/com/{your_project}/MainApplication.java

Also, commenting out line number 43 in this file android/app/src/debug/java/com/**/ReactNativeFlipper.java

line43: builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));

Answer (score 0):

None of the issues in the other answers were causing my problem, but after digging more into Axios error response, I found out that Nginx was responding with error `413 Request Entity Too Large`.

Adding `client_max_body_size 50M` to the http section of `nginx.conf` file solved the issue.