# Upload image through axios in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

I've been dealing with this problem for a while now apparently you can upload a image using `FormData` and appending the file but I am still unable to get this to work. I have already tried with the following threads:

- [React Native - Axios - Trying to upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936988/react-native-axios-trying-to-upload-image)
- [form post with file attach throws network error / React Native + react native Image picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046007/form-post-with-file-attach-throws-network-error-react-native-react-native-im)
- [How do I set multipart in axios with react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878838/how-do-i-set-multipart-in-axios-with-react/42096508#42096508)

My first problem revolves around `FormData().append()`, in most solutions a blob/file is configured using the `uri` property but I **don't have** access to this property (Is this related to Typescript?). So something like this:

```
formData.append("profile_photo", {
     uri: values.imageURI
});
```

Here's the error TS is returning:

```
Argument of type '{ uri: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'uri' does not exist in type 'Blob'.ts(2345)
```

Another key points is setting up my axios client with the `Content-Type` header, I've done this during my POST request like so:

```
 // Perform a profile post request
const profileResponse = await loginClient.post(
      "/user_profile",
       formData,
       {
           headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
       }
);
```

**But** by logging my request with Axios' interceptors, here how the request headers look like:

```json
    headers:
    Accept: "application/json"
    Authorization: "Bearer 36|8SVw1DntRKni0sUn4NDX9moLluCHyYcZSadfgI5B"
    __proto__: Object
```

Just a few observations:

- The image uri is changed using [expo-image-picker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/).
- I'm using [Formik](https://formik.org/) to build my form.
- I'm using Typescript.

Comment: `formData.append("profile_photo", values.imageURI);` ? [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) - oops, nevermind, react-native may be different - sorry

Comment: `values` contains my submit form values, `values.imageURI` contains the image local uri.

Comment: yes, it does - not sure how that relates to the type of data formData.append expects (string or blob I think the error states - you're passing an object) - try [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441963/how-to-use-formdata-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using the [Form-Data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) module, then you can easily pass in the uri like so:

```
formData.append("profile_photo", {
        uri: values.imageURI,
        name: "image.png",
        type: "image/png",
});
```

This could be improved by extracting the type from the uri tho.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send these 3 values while uploading a file.

1. URI.
2. Name.
3. Type.

You can get all these values from the file picker.
Send it as

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("profile_photo", {
  uri: values.imageURI,
  name: values.name || "profile_photo.png",
  type: values.type || "image/png"
});

axios.post('upload_file', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
});
```

Comment: I was setting these 3 properties but I had to install the Form-Data module in order to get it to work.

Comment: FormData is actually a constructor and it is inbuilt with javascript

Comment: Yes, but it would not allow me to use the `uri` nor `name` properties. I guess RN works differently. [Doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)